# Angular download csv file on browser

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, csv, servlets

I have Rest API that sends the csv String like

```
"aa,bb\n cc,dd"
```

Here is the Rest Service code:

```
@GET
    @Path("/getCsv")
    @Produces({"text/csv"})
    public String getCSV(   ) {
        return "aa,ba,\n,ac,da";    
    }
```

On UI side

Angular resource code to make get request code is as below:

```
angular.module('csvHelper', ['ngResource','configuration']).factory('csvHelper', function($resource,$rootScope){
            return $resource(URL+'/api/getCsv/', {}, { 
                query: {method:'GET', params:{}, cache :true}
            });
            });
```

Code that makes get request and generate csv is as follows

```
csvHelper.query({}, function(response) {
                 def.resolve(response);  
                 },function(response) {
                 def.reject(response);  
                 });

           var prom = def.promise;
            prom.then(function(text) {              
                $window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(text));            
            }, function(error) {
                    console.log('promise failed', error);
            });
```

In network tab I see rest API sending the data properly:

```
   "aa,ba,\n,ac,da"
```

But when I download the csv file, inside it  I see

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

What am I doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I tired to print response on console and this is what I saw:

```
[e { 0="a",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="a",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0=",",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="b",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="a",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0=",",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="\n",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0=",",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="a",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="c",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0=",",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="d",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}, e { 0="a",  $get=function(),  $save=function(),  more...}]
```

**EDIT 2**

I changed the logic to use $http like this:

```
$http.get("http://myurl.com/api/getcsv")
              .success(function (response) {console.log(success)});
```

I see the success printed on console but I don't see popup.

when I hit http://myurl.com/api/getcsv in browser I see popup to download file.

What am I missing

**EDIT 3**

This change worked.

```
 $http.get(compiledUrl).then(function (response) {               
                          $window.open("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(response.data));                             
                  },function(response){
                      console.log("error");                  
                  });
```

Comment: Seems like you need `JSON.stringify(text)`. You should also use `encodeURI()` instead of encodeURIComponent()

Comment: yeah, try encodeURI instead. it seems that JSON.stringify wouldn't be needed because you're returning text.

Comment: It is not Json Data . How can I use JSON.stringify?

Comment: refer to second comment

Comment: sorry my bad... Didn't see your second comment. tried encodeURI() and it didn't work

Comment: so, for some reason, you're not returning a plain string. try changing the produces annotation such that it returns @Produces({"text/plain"}). the goal is to get your response to be a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to download the CSV string, you should use $http and not $resource.

> **$resource returns:** A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions.

[$resource @ angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: $http returns promise... So again it will be same logic right

Comment: Please edit the code in your original question with the most updated code so I can take a look... or put it in a plunkr.

Comment: It worked . Thanks. I changed the code as showed in edit 3

Answer (score 0):

you can use two custom function

1

```
function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData,ShowLabel) {    
  var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : 
SONData;   
 var CSV = '';       
if (ShowLabel) {     
var row = "";
 for (var index in arrData[0]) {
     row += index + ',';
 }
 row = row.slice(0, -1);
 CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
 var row = "";
 for (var index in arrData[i]) {
    var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
    row += arrValue + ',';
 }
 row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
 CSV += row + '\r\n';
  }
  if (CSV == '') {        
 growl.error("Invalid data");
 return;
  }   
  var fileName = "Result";
  if(msieversion()){
  var IEwindow = window.open();
  IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
  IEwindow.document.close();
  IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
  IEwindow.close();
  } else {
   var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
   var link = document.createElement("a");  
   link.href = uri;
   link.style = "visibility:hidden";
   link.download = fileName + ".csv";
   document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
   document.body.removeChild(link);
 }
}
```

2

```
function msieversion() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 
  if (msie != -1 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number 
  {
return true;
  } else { // If another browser, 
   return false;
  }    
return false; 
}
```

and use above function to have downloadable result.csv file

```
  if(data.userlog == '')
            return;
        JSONToCSVConvertor(data.userlog, true);
```